# How to write an SQL query to get the number of completed and cancelled deliveries by excluding the clone delivery cancellation?

Tags: sql, mysql-workbench, parent-child, clone, mysql-8.0

| Id | deliverytype | parentId | status |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | parentDelivery1 | 0 | cancelled |
| 2 | cloneDelivery1a | 1 | cancelled |
| 3 | cloneDelivery1b | 1 | completed |
| 4 | cloneDelivery1c | 1 | cancelled |
| 5 | parentDelivery2 | 0 | cancelled |
| 6 | cloneDelivery2a | 5 | cancelled |
| 7 | cloneDelivery2b | 5 | cancelled |
| 8 | cloneDelivery 2c | 5 | cancelled |
| 9 | parentDelivery3 | 0 | completed |
| 10 | parentDelivery4 | 0 | cancelled |

expected output(for this example):

| number of completed deliveries | number of cancelled deliveries |
| --- | --- |
| 2 | 2 |

All parent deliveries have 0 as parent id and clone deliveries have its parentId in parentId column
Here if even 1 delivery out of parent and clones is completed then it should count as completed and all clone cancellation should be eliminated. 
*Parent deliveries can have 0 clones 
*Clone deliveries will not have clone of its own 
*If Parent delivery is cancelled but any 1 of its clone is completed then it should be considered as 1 completed and 0 cancelled(the other cancellations should not be counted under cancelled deliveries)

If all the delivery out of parent and clones is cancelled then it should be counted as 1 cancellation. How can I write an SQL query for this?

I am using MySQL workbench community version 8.0.29

Comment: Please provide both sample input and expected outcome as tables, thanks.

Comment: Id    deliverytype      parentId      status
1    parentDelivery1      0          cancelled
2    cloneDelivery1a      1          cancelled
3    cloneDelivery1b      1          completed
4    cloneDelivery 1c      1          cancelled
5    parentDelivery2      0          cancelled
6    cloneDelivery2a      2          cancelled
7    cloneDelivery2b      2          cancelled
8    cloneDelivery 2c      2          cancelled this is sample input.. sample output can be like no of completed deliveries=1, no of cancelled deliveries=1 (for this example)

Comment: @Raksha can you provide the output **table**, related to the shared input, by editing the question?

Comment: I've started fixing your formatting for you, please could you finish it? Then you'll know what to do next time.

Comment: Can a parent delivery have Zero clone deliveries? Can a clone delivery also have its own clones? Can a parent delivery have status=completed and all the clones have status=cancelled?

Comment: Please specify in the question, and the tags, which version of MySQL you are using. MySQL8, for example, has functionality not available in MySQL5.x

Comment: @MatBailie thank you for helping me fix the formatting. Parent deliveries can have 0 clones.. Clone deliveries will not have clones of its own...  parent delivery can have status=completed with all the clones status=cancelled.

Answer (score 0):

My paraphrased logic...

- if the parent says completed, it is completed
- if parent says cancelled, but any children say completed, it is completed
- else, parent and all children say cancelled, so it is cancelled

Which gives...

```
WITH
  parent_outcome AS
(
  SELECT
    p.id,
    CASE
      WHEN MAX(p.status) = 'completed' THEN 1
      WHEN MAX(c.status) = 'completed' THEN 1
      ELSE 0
    END
      AS is_completed
  FROM
    your_table AS p
  LEFT JOIN
    your_table AS c
       ON c.parent_id = p.id
  WHERE
    p.parent_id = 0
  GROUP BY
    p.id
)
SELECT
             SUM(is_completed) AS is_completed,
  COUNT(*) - SUM(is_completed) AS is_cancelled
FROM
  parent_outcome
```